# not recognizing a declared variables in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

The last but 3rd line of code is not recognizing variables that I have declared and filled with strings.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputNumber = "1979";

        string input1 = inputNumber.Substring(0, 1);
        string input2 = inputNumber.Substring(1, 1);
        string input3 = inputNumber.Substring(2, 1);
        string input4 = inputNumber.Substring(3, 1);

        int intInput1;
        int intInput2;
        int intInput3;
        int intInput4;

        intInput1 = Convert.ToInt32(input1);
        intInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(input2);
        intInput3 = Convert.ToInt32(input3);
        intInput4 = Convert.ToInt32(input4);

        string stringOutput1;
        string stringOutput2;
        string stringOutput3;
        string stringOutput4;

        // 1000 Input.
        switch (intInput1)
        {
            case 1:
                stringOutput1 = "M";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //100 Input
        switch (intInput2)
        {
            case 9:
                stringOutput2 = "CM";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //10 Input
        switch (intInput3)
        {
            case 7:
                stringOutput3 = "LXX";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //1 Input
        switch (intInput4)
        {
            case 9:
                stringOutput4 = "IX";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //Use of unassigned local variable error is showing for 'stringOutput1', 'stringOutput2', 'stringOutput3' and 'stringOutput4'
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}{2}{3}{4} in Roman Numerals",inputNumber, stringOutput1, stringOutput2, stringOutput3, stringOutput4);
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

P.S. I know that the variables are being filled by commenting out

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}{2}{3}{4} in Roman Numerals",inputNumber, stringOutput1, stringOutput2, stringOutput3, stringOutput4);
```

and using break point and stepping over the code.

Comment: `//Use of unassigned local variable error is showing for 'stringOutput1', 'stringOutput2', 'stringOutput3' and 'stringOutput4'` ..

Comment: The compiler wants to prevent you from careless mistakes. It's not guaranteed that those variables are always initialized. You're using a `switch-case` which only initializes `stringOutput1` if `intInput1==1`. In all other cases it's still `null`. The same applies to the other variables. Use the `default`-section to assign a default-value or assign it in the first place(f.e. `string stringOutput1 = null;`)

Answer (score 3):

This is because your variables might not have been assigned anything yet.  Variables must be guaranteed to have been assigned something before they can be used.  As a simple fix, you can use declarations like this:

```
string stringOutput1 = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning nulls to the declarations

```
string stringOutput1 = null;
string stringOutput2 = null;
string stringOutput3 = null;
string stringOutput4 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your variables, do it like this.

```
string stringOutput1 , stringOutput1, stringOutput3, stringOutput4 = string.Empty;
```

and you can also assign default values per variable.

```
string stringOutput1 = "foo1", stringOutput1 = "foo2"
, stringOutput3= "foo3", stringOutput4 = "foo4";
```